# Handle licensing error?

Tags: android

I'm adding licensing to my app, under allow(), I start the activity. Under dontAllow, I display a dialog saying, not licensed, go to market. Under applicationError, I'm not sure.

I don't want my app to be inaccessible because of an error in code but if I start my activity there, then licensing could just be bypassed if data access is not available. How is everybody handling this?

Comment: What do you mean "data access is not available"? Is it an internet connection?

Comment: yes, data/internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

LVL caches last successful license check status and calls `allow()` method even if there's no internet connection. But after several tries or after certain time it starts treating license as expired one and calls `dontAllow()`. Validity period and retries count comes from Android Market, so these values aren't hardcoded in LVL. You can get additional informatoin here: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#extras